# Unable to retrieve value of parameter from testng.xml when test class is run as 'TestNG Test'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

In order to retrieve browser type(on which I want to run Selenium tests) from `testng.xml`, I've written code like following -

```
public class TestClass {

    @BeforeClass
      public void beforeClass(ITestContext context) {
          String browser = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("browser");

          if(browser.equals("firefox")){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          }
.
.
.
```

Following is my `testng.xml` -

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Task-Manager-Suite" verbose="10" >
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
  <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
      <class name="org.test.st.StackOverflowTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

When I run `testng.xml`, test run fine and `browser` is set with value mention in `parameter` tag in the `testng.xml`

But when I open another test class file by right click on it and selecting 'Run As' -> 'TestNG Test', value of `browser` is set to `null`. It doesn't pick up value from `testng.xml`

Is there anything after doing that I can run test class file and value of browser will be picked up from `testng.xml`?

When I want to check tests written by me, every time I've to go to `testng.xml` and update `class` tag with the file name which I want to run.

That's why I'm looking for something by which I can avoid editing `testng.xml` every time I want to check tests written by me.

Please point me some blog or github link where this kind of problem has been handled.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you run from test class as Run as > testng test, TestNg will create a custom xml file, in which the parameter that you have defined will not be there. So to get your parameters in suite file, select your suite file and Run as> TestNG Suite.

If you insist on running from your test class, set your Suite file  as Template XML file in eclipse in Project>Properties>Template XML file.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
@Parameters{"browser"}
public void beforeClass(@Optional("firefox") String browser) {
    // ...
}
```